# Change style / color of blocks of code in blogdown

Tags: css, hugo, blogdown

I'm working on my new blog using @Yihui Xie `blogdown` package in RStudio and can't figure out

#### How to change the default colouring scheme for blocks of code?

My `blogdown` installation uses [cactus-plus](https://github.com/nodejh/hugo-theme-cactus-plus) template and out of the box it renders code with a palette that is hard to see (at least for me):
[image]

Looks like `highlight: zenburn` but I'm not sure.

In a regular `RMarkdownw` document I would change html output in yaml to:

```
output:
  html_document:
    theme: united
    highlight: tango
```

But with hugo themes and blogdown I'm not sure where and how make these changes.

Comment: If you want to implement it along with config.toml, which is interesting because you can properly add new languages, or change version of highlightjs, you can have a look at this commit I proposed for a theme: https://github.com/jpescador/hugo-future-imperfect/pull/108/commits/4151133f629d76fe5a2b2fb144f69562b1f96bbb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below I outline how I managed to hack it for my theme. FWI I am still in the learning stage, so my way may not be the most optimal solution.

In the theme directory, head over to /partials/head.html or header.html. Add the the following lines of html, this will use the CDN resources directly without having to download a custom copy:

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/highlight.js/9.6.0/styles/default.min.css">`
`<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/highlight.js/9.6.0/highlight.min.js"></script>`
`<script>hljs.initHighlightingOnLoad();</script>`

Replace the default.min.css based on the style you would like to use. I am using the `github` style.
Or alternatively you can download a custom copy from the highlight.js website, extract the zip folder and copy the highlight.js and the CSS style of you choice to the relevant directories under you website.

Edit:
An even easier implementation is making use of the instructions from Yihui:
Add the following code to your `foot_custom.html` under the /layouts/ directory. .

`<script src="//cdn.bootcss.com/highlight.js/9.12.0/highlight.min.js"></script>`
`<script src="//cdn.bootcss.com/highlight.js/9.12.0/languages/r.min.js"></script>`

`<script>
hljs.configure({languages: []});
hljs.initHighlightingOnLoad();
</script>`

The last code makes sure highlight.js doesn't automatically guess languages. Which you can manually set in your `config.toml` e.g 
  `highlightjsVersion = "9.12.0"
  highlightjsCDN = "//cdn.bootcss.com"
  highlightjsLang = ["r", "yaml", "tex", "python"]
  highlightjsTheme = "github`

In the head_custom, add the following code:
`<link href="//cdn.bootcss.com/highlight.js/9.12.0/styles/github.min.css" rel="stylesheet">`

For code block customization, use CSS.

Additional resources [here](https://github.com/yihui/hugo-xmin/pull/5)

Answer (score 1):

This is an old post, but if an answer is needed, here is one.

The simplest solution is to go into your config.toml file and change the desired theme quoted in:  highlightjsTheme = "yourdesiredtheme"

For a list of suitable options, check this link out: https://highlightjs.org/static/demo/

I would recommend evaluating all possible styles **AFTER** you've set the Language Categories -> Scientific -> R.